# Is transactional @observes working for fired events on JBoss AS 7?

Tags: events, jboss, observer-pattern, jboss7.x

In order to use events only listened if a transaction succeeds or fails, I'm following the given doc about transactional observers :
http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/1.1.0.Final/en-US/html_single/#d0e4075

... but cannot manage to make my code work on JBoss AS7.

Here's my EJB:

```
@LocalBean
@Stateful
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NEVER)
public class MyController
{
    @Inject
    private transient Event<MyEvent> myEventLauncher;

    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void save()
    {
        myEventLauncher.fire(new MyEvent());
    }

    @AfterCompletion
    protected void afterSave(boolean isCommitted)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

And here my basic listener:

```
public class MyHandler
{
    protected void listenMyEvent(@Observes(during=TransactionPhase.AFTER_SUCCESS) MyEvent event)
    {
        // do stuff
    }

    protected void listenMyEvent2(@Observes(during=TransactionPhase.AFTER_FAILURE) MyEvent event)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

I can say I'm in a transaction when the event is fired, because the `afterSave` method of the EJB is called. Alas, the methods `listenMyEvent` and `listenMyEvent2` are always called both, like if I was not in a transactional context.

I tried the same code on GlassFish 3 and it perfectly works, so I guess there is a problem with JBoss AS 7, but I cannot find any bug report about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as my current tests made me think that transactional observers are not working in JBoss AS 7, I managed to do a workaround I gave here for people who are interested.

First, we need qualifier annotations: `Immediate`, `AfterFailure` and `AfterSuccess`.

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER })
public @interface AfterFailure
{}

@Qualifier
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER })
public @interface AfterSuccess
{}

@Qualifier
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER })
public @interface Immediate
{}
```

Also, three basic `AnnotationLiteral` to create in runtime instances of this three annotations.

Then, we need a encapsulator for our true events, that I named `SpecialEvent`.

```
public class SpecialEvent
{
    private Object event; // the real event you want

    public SpecialEvent(Object event)
    {
        super();
        this.event = event;
    }

    public Object getEvent()
    {
        return event;
    }
}
```

And at last, an observer for this special event and an interceptor for classes where you want to fire this kind of events (full explanation below).

```
@RequestScoped
public class SpecialEventObserver
{
    @Inject
    private Event<Object> anyEventFirer; // firer for real events
    private List<Object> events; // queued events

    public SpecialEventObserver()
    {
        events = new ArrayList<Object>();
    }

    // remove all queued events
    public void reset()
    {
        this.events.clear();
    }

    public void fireAfterFailureEvents() throws Exception
    {
        this.fireAllEventsOnce(new AfterFailureLiteral());
    }

    public void fireAfterSuccessEvents() throws Exception
    {
        this.fireAllEventsOnce(new AfterSuccessLiteral());
    }

    protected void listenSpecialEvent(@Observes SpecialEvent specialEvent)
    {
        Object event = specialEvent.getEvent();
        this.events.add(event);
        this.fireEvent(event, new ImmediateLiteral());
    }

    protected void fireAllEventsOnce(Annotation qualifier) throws Exception
    {
        try
        {
            for (Object event : this.events)
            {
                this.fireEvent(event, qualifier);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
        finally
        {
            this.events.clear();
        }
    }

    protected void fireEvent(Object event, Annotation qualifier)
    {
        Event eventFirer = anyEventFirer.select(event.getClass(), qualifier);
        eventFirer.fire(event);
    }
}

@Interceptor
@LocalInterception
public class MyInterceptor implements Serializable
{   
    @Inject
    private SpecialEventObserver specialEventObserver;

    @AroundInvoke
    public Object intercept(InvocationContext ic) throws Exception
    {   
        specialEventObserver.reset();
        try
        {
            // call the real method
            Object proceedResult = ic.proceed();

            // real method succeeded, fire successful events
            specialEventObserver.fireAfterSuccessEvents();

            return proceedResult;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // real method failed, fire failed events
            specialEventObserver.fireAfterFailureEvents();

            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

The mechanism is quite simple:

- When you want to fire an event, fire a `SpecialEvent` that hold the true event.
- The `SpecialEventObserver` will catch any `SpecialEvent` and will immediately fire your own event with an `Immediate` qualifier. It will also queue the events for the after completion part.
- At the end of your own method call (`ic.proceed` in the interceptor), `MyInterceptor` will ask the `SpecialEventObserver` either to fire again all events with a `AfterFailure` qualifier or a `AfterSuccess` qualifier, depending of the success of your method.
- In place of `@Observes(during=...)`, your own observers have to observe events with the right qualifier, like `@Observes @Immediate`, `@Observes @AfterFailure` or `@Observes @AfterSuccess`.

The behavior is not exactly the one that provides the native `@Observes(during=...)`. The after completion part is not based on the transaction state, but on your own method call success:

- In JaveEE6, transactional observers on after success or after failure phases must be immediately called if you're not in a transaction, like a `IN_PROGRESS` would do.
- In this workaround, observers on after success or after failure phases will always be called at the end of the method, and only if it succeeded or failed.

Answer (score 0):

This works with version 7.1.0.Final which is supposedly (-> with Jboss you never know) fully Java EE compliant. Also your bean is not thread-safe as it uses list instead of a concurrent queue.

Comment: Well, we'll try that on 7.1.0 when Seam Faces will be successfully included in it (there's an issue about it that is blocking us). Also, I think my bean can use a `List` and be thread-unsafe, as it is `@RequestScoped`.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I figured out that the weld spec "defines" an undefined behaviour regarding the transactional context of an observer method for certain values of the "during" attribute. Seems that even if from control flow perspective a transaction should be still available it is not. Declaring the the observer method as requiring a transaction does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Your observer methods need REQUIRES_NEW, as stated here :

[http://www.seamframework.org/Documentation/WhyIsThereNoActiveTransactionInMySFSBTransactionalObserver](http://seamframework.org/Documentation/WhyIsThereNoActiveTransactionInMySFSBTransactionalObserver.html)